# CSS: Pure form css is not putting color in button

Tags: css

This is what I am trying to implement

http://purecss.io/forms/

Here is what I have tried

http://plnkr.co/edit/B2lPwBgY61fSzg4nbaeD?p=preview

**Problem?**

The button color is not showing up

Is there anything I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: The `.notice` style rule isn't defined in `pure.css`. You would need to define it yourself, and then set the appropriate `background-color` and `color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color of button that you have shown in your first link is from `.notice` class. But in your example that you have created doesn't have any `.notice` class, so just add it to your css and use it.

```
.notice {
background-color: #61B842;
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pure CSS site has styling for the `.notice` class while the Pure CSS file you linked has no such styling.  Simply add `.notice {
    background-color: rgb(97, 184, 66);}` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

Your not missing anything, `rgb(230, 230, 230)` or `#E6E6E6` is the default background-color for ''.pure-button'. Simply override it in your own css file, e.g.

```
.pure-button {
    background-color: green;
}
```